# How to resize end and start icon of a text input layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, mobile

I am having trouble with the size of end and start icon of my text input layout, as they appear too big. I have been able of fixing the size of the start icon by adding a 50% padding on the drawable when creating it, but I am unable to do the same to the end icon (like the password eye thing and the clear_text icon).

I suspect it has something to do with my app's theme. I have tried to add an iconSize, drawablePadding,itemPadding, etc. atributes to my text input style, but none of that works.

[image: A screenshot of the bugged icons of the text input layout]

Here is the code of my text input layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/introduce_tu_email"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_person"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text">
  

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My theme and styles:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Academia" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/button1Style</item>
    <item name ="textInputStyle">@style/textInputEditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="appBarLayoutStyle">@style/appBarStyle</item>
    <item name ="android:windowBackground">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/opensans_medium</item>
    <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/imageButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceBodyLarge">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium</item>
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/bottomNavigatationStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="textInputEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name ="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="endIconTint">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="passwordToggleTint">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/complementary_theme_color</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/complementary_theme_color</item>
    <item name="startIconTint">@color/theme_color</item>
</style>
```

Also, this bugs have happened after I updated Android Studio to Dolphin version.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's because of `imageButtonStyle` in your Theme: **Theme.Academia**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting the style to your `TextInputEditText` view. Add the attribute `style="@style/textInputEditTextStyle"` and it should work. Like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    style="@style/textInputEditTextStyle"
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
```

Comment: No, I have already tried that and it does not work. Thanks anyways